# Make OR-Tools find values and operators for math puzzles

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm playing around with OR-Tools to create puzzles like `a < b, a < c, b < c, c = d`. The idea is to give people these equations and they need to find the numbers that need to be entered into the variables a-d to create a valid solution. OR-Tools should create solutions and I remove the numbers to create the puzzle. Some numbers will be left to give a start. For example, in the above equations `b=2` might be given, the player can then figure out that `a` must be `1`. Players are given the variables, the equations with operators, and some start values and need to figure out the set of variable assignments that make the set of equations valid.

Creating variables and constraints like this works like a charm:

```py
model.NewIntVar(min_number, max_number, 'a')
model.NewIntVar(min_number, max_number, 'b')
model.NewIntVar(min_number, max_number, 'c')
model.NewIntVar(min_number, max_number, 'd')

model.Add(a < b)
model.Add(a < c)
model.Add(b < c)
model.Add(c = d)
```

This makes or-tools find the operands.

Now I also want the mathematical operators to be "calculated", so that I don't have to provide them.
My current workaround is randomizing them with `operator` before creating the constraints like this:

```py
def rand_op():
  return random.choice(['<', '>', '='])

ops = {
    '<': operator.lt,
    '>': operator.gt,
    '=': operator.eq
    }

model.Add(ops.get(rand_op())(a, b))
model.Add(ops.get(rand_op())(b, c))
...
```

That does solve my problem, but obviously kind of takes some magic from or-tools as with this randomness many many problems that do not have a solution are created and it takes quite a lot of loops to find solutions.

So I'm wondering how I could achieve this in a better way. One naive approach would be to work with allowed assignments. So I would take two variables for the operands and one variable for the operator (with encoded operator signs) and then make allowed assignments:

```py
ops = {
    '<': 0,
    '>': 1,
    '=': 2
    }
a = model.NewIntVar(min_number, max_number, 'a')
b = model.NewIntVar(min_number, max_number, 'b')
op_ab = model.NewIntVar(min_op_number, max_op_number, 'op_ab')

model.AddAllowedAssignments([a, b, op_ab], [
  (1, 2, 0),
  (2, 1, 1),
  (1, 1, 2),
  ...
])
```

I'm pretty sure this will work, but it would create quite a lot of allowed constraints. Depending on the size of the puzzle it could go into the millions. The more variables and operators available the more constraints would be needed and the larger the domain for the variables the larger the list of allowed assignments per constraint. So it would grow horizontally and vertically in size, probably exponentially.

Is there another approach I could use? Any ideas on a more performant way? Any constraints that I should look into?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly your requirements for the "puzzles" are. Are you trying to formulate puzzles with a given number of variables and their allowed values such that you can give some statements about pairs of variables like `a < b` which all taken together lead to unique solutions? What kind of statements are allowed?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins I improved the puzzle description. Is it better to understand now?

Comment: Yes thanks, it's better to understand now. It's not stated but I assume the domains of the variables (`min_number, max_number`) are either given to the people solving the puzzles or can be determined from the puzzle statements, and that there should be a unique solution to the puzzle. Your goal is to automatically generate such puzzles assisted by OR-Tools.

Comment: My idea is that after creating the variables, add every combination of pairs of variables and operators as constraints with an `OnlyEnforceIf(IsInPuzzle[i])` clause. The `IsInPuzzle[i]`  are boolean IntVar's which signify that the given constraint is part of the puzzle. These `IsInPuzzle[i]` variables would be the decision variables for the problem. You would look for solutions where as few of these are 1 as possible such that a) a solution is possible and b) the domains of the original variables shrink to 1 value (uniqueness of solution). I'm still thinking about how to enforce uniqueness...

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins, thx. Yes, min_ and max_numbers are known to the player. I also thought about `OnlyEnforceIf()` and was hoping to get something like `OnlyEnforceIf(op_1 == '<')` but soon had to realise that OnlyEnforceIf only takes boolean parameters. So my next idea was to create boolean vars like `op_1_gt, op_1_lt` and have a constraint that only one of them can be used. Then `Add(a < b).OnlyEnforceIf(op_1_lt)`could be a working constraint. But haven't had time to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this; I hope I haven't missed some important requirement.

The following model uses OR-tools CP-SAT solver in Python. It is a quite direct approach to the problem, connecting the operators and the variables using `OnlyEnforceIf` via an array of boolean of length 3 (for the 3 operators) and then require that the sum of these is 1 (exactly one operator).

The model generates all possible solutions given `n` (number of variables) and their domain (`min_val` and `max_val`).

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp


"""
Print solutions
"""
class SolutionPrinter(cp.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    def __init__(self, x,ops,ops_d,num_sols=0):
        cp.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__x = x
        self.__ops = ops
        self.__ops_d = ops_d        
        self.__num_sols = num_sols
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def OnSolutionCallback(self):
        self.__solution_count += 1
        
        x = [self.Value(v) for v in self.__x]
        n = len(x)
        # ops = [self.Value(v) for v in self.__ops]
        ops_d = self.__ops_d
        num_sols = self.__num_sols
        print("===================")
        print("Problem:")
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1,n):
                op = ops_d[self.Value(self.__ops[i,j])]
                print(f"x{i} {op} x{j}")
        print()

        print("Solution:")
        print("x:",x)        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1,n):
                op = ops_d[self.Value(self.__ops[i,j])]
                print(f"{x[i]} {op} {x[j]}")
        print()


        if num_sols > 0 and self.__solution_count >= num_sols:
            self.StopSearch()

    def SolutionCount(self):
        return self.__solution_count



def generate_math_puzzle(n=3,min_val=1,max_val=10,num_sols=0):
    model = cp.CpModel()

    lt = 0 # <
    eq = 1 # >
    gt = 2 # =
    ops_a = [lt,eq,gt]
    num_ops = len(ops_a)

    # loopup for presentation
    ops_d = {0:"<",
             1:"=",
             2:">"}

    num_pairs = (n*(n-1)) // 2
    
    # variables
    x = [model.NewIntVar(min_val, max_val, f'x[{i}]') for i in range(n)]

    # We have n-1 operators
    # ops = [model.NewIntVar(lt, gt, f'ops[{i}]') for i in range(n-1)]

    ops = {}
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            ops[i,j] = model.NewIntVar(lt,gt,f"op_{i}_{j}")
            bs = [model.NewBoolVar(f"bs_{i}_{j}") for j in range(num_ops)]
            for op in ops_a:
                model.Add(ops[i,j]==op).OnlyEnforceIf(bs[op])
            model.Add(sum(bs) == 1) # exactly one operation
                
            model.Add(x[i]  < x[j]).OnlyEnforceIf(bs[lt])       
            model.Add(x[i] == x[j]).OnlyEnforceIf(bs[eq])      
            model.Add(x[i]  > x[j]).OnlyEnforceIf(bs[gt])

    print("ModelStats:", model.ModelStats())
    
    solver = cp.CpSolver() 
    # solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8
    # solution_printer = SolutionPrinter(x_flat) 
    solution_printer = SolutionPrinter(x,ops,ops_d,num_sols)
    status = solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)

    if not status in [cp.OPTIMAL,cp.FEASIBLE]:
        print("No solution!")
        
    print()
    print("NumSolutions:", solution_printer.SolutionCount())    
    print("NumConflicts:", solver.NumConflicts())
    print("NumBranches:", solver.NumBranches())
    print("WallTime:", solver.WallTime())


n=3
min_val=1
max_val=10
num_sols = 0
generate_math_puzzle(n,min_val,max_val)
```

Here are some solutions for the simple problem with `n=3`, `min_val=1`, and `max_val=10`.

```
Problem:
x0 > x1
x0 < x2
x1 < x2

Solution:
x: [2, 1, 3]
2 > 1
2 < 3
1 < 3

===================
Problem:
x0 = x1
x0 < x2
x1 < x2

Solution:
x: [1, 1, 2]
1 = 1
1 < 2
1 < 2
```

In all, it's 1000 solutions and takes about 0.1s to generate them all.

Here is a result for a larger problem `n=30`, `min_val=1`, and `max_val=100`:

```
===================
Problem:
x0 = x1
x0 < x2
x0 < x3
x0 < x4
x0 < x5
x0 < x6
x0 < x7
x0 < x8
x0 < x9
x1 < x2
x1 < x3
x1 < x4
x1 < x5
x1 < x6
x1 < x7
x1 < x8
x1 < x9
x2 < x3
x2 < x4
x2 < x5
x2 < x6
x2 < x7
x2 < x8
x2 < x9
x3 < x4
x3 < x5
x3 < x6
x3 < x7
x3 < x8
x3 < x9
x4 < x5
x4 < x6
x4 < x7
x4 < x8
x4 < x9
x5 < x6
x5 < x7
x5 < x8
x5 < x9
x6 < x7
x6 < x8
x6 < x9
x7 < x8
x7 < x9
x8 < x9

Solution:
x: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 65]
1 = 1
1 < 2
1 < 3
1 < 4
1 < 5
1 < 6
1 < 7
1 < 15
1 < 65
1 < 2
1 < 3
1 < 4
1 < 5
1 < 6
1 < 7
1 < 15
1 < 65
2 < 3
2 < 4
2 < 5
2 < 6
2 < 7
2 < 15
2 < 65
3 < 4
3 < 5
3 < 6
3 < 7
3 < 15
3 < 65
4 < 5
4 < 6
4 < 7
4 < 15
4 < 65
5 < 6
5 < 7
5 < 15
5 < 65
6 < 7
6 < 15
6 < 65
7 < 15
7 < 65
15 < 65
```

Note that for some problem instances (i.e. pairs of `xi op xj`) there might be multiple solutions.

Comment: I had understood that the solution to each puzzle is supposed to be unique--some of the puzzles output here will have multiple solutions. How would you approach ensuring a "unique solution" requirement? Do you have an idea on how to make the puzzles "minimal" (i.e. if `a0 < a1` and `a1 < a2` have been stated, we also don't need the redundant `a1 < a2`)?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins My model does not enforce either of these requirements.  I must have missed the requirement that the solutions must be unique (and I commented on that last in my post) as well as minimal. But to be a good puzzle it should at least be a unique solution. Well, I let the model stand as it shows a little how to work with OnlyEnforceIf.

Comment: My answer also doesn't fulfill the minimality requirement but does produce puzzles with unique solutions. I couldn't think of any way to model the uniqueness requirement using the OR-tools CP-SAT solver which is why I used the older one.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins Well, one way would be to add an external loop of the model,  then check that if a (tentative) solution is unique and  only print those solutions.

Answer (score 0):

@bechtold, your problem was interesting enough that I attempted a solution. It is based on my last comment to your post.

Caveat: It's not exactly what you want because

- I use c#, not python (I simply don't have enough experience in python and don't have a working installation of it) and
- I used the old solver (Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver) instead of the newer SAT solver (Google.OrTools.Sat); I'll explain the reasons for that below.

**Class Term**

First I created a class `Term` with some overloaded operators to make it easier to create the expressions for the puzzle.

The overloaded operators + and * allow creation of terms like `2 * a` or `a + 2` to make the puzzles a little more interesting. These create a new `IntVar` and constrain it to be equal to the arithmetic operation on the original variable.

The overloaded operators >, == and < are a little more subtle. They create a constraint like `a < b`, but do not add it directly to the model. Instead, they also create a new `enforced` BoolVar (the `IsInPuzzle` variable of my comment), and constrain it to be less than or equal to the `Var()` of the constraint. This effectively makes the constraint optional, because depending on whether `enforced == 1` or is 0 or has an open domain, the constraint does or doesn't have to be fulfilled. This is pretty much the equivalent of the `OnlyEnforceIf()` method on constraints in the new SAT solver.

The overloaded operators return Expression objects (see below).

The class includes some housekeeping methods and an overridden `ToString()` method for easier output.

```
using Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver;
using System;

namespace SO69225141_create_puzzles
{
#pragma warning disable CS0660 // Type defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.Equals(object o)
#pragma warning disable CS0661 // Type defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.GetHashCode()
    internal class Term
#pragma warning restore CS0661 // Type defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.GetHashCode()
#pragma warning restore CS0660 // Type defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.Equals(object o)
    {
        protected Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver.Solver solver;
        public string name { get; private set; }
        public IntVar intVar { get; private set; }

        private string basedOnVariableName;

        public Term(Solver solver_, string name_, long minNumber_, long maxNumber_)
        {
            this.solver = solver_ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(solver_));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name_))
            {
                name = "unknown";
            }
            else
            {
                name = name_;
            }
            intVar = solver.MakeIntVar(minNumber_, maxNumber_, name);
            basedOnVariableName = name;
        }

        public Term(Solver solver_, string name_) : this(solver_, name_, PuzzleCreator.minNumber, PuzzleCreator.maxNumber) { }

        // Returns true if this term is based on the same variable as the other term (e.g. true for "(a + 2)" given "a" but not for "(3 * b)".
        public bool isBasedOnSameVariableAs(Term other)
        {
            return this.basedOnVariableName == other.basedOnVariableName;
        }

        // Creates a new Term whose IntVar is constrained to be term + val
        public static Term operator +(Term term, long val)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(term, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(term)); }
            Term newTerm = new Term(term.solver, $"({term.name} + {val})", term.intVar.Min() + val, term.intVar.Max() + val);
            newTerm.basedOnVariableName = term.basedOnVariableName;
            term.solver.Add(newTerm.intVar == (term.intVar + val));
            return newTerm;
        }

        // Creates a new Term whose IntVar is constrained to be val * term
        public static Term operator *(long val, Term term)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(term, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(term)); }
            Term newTerm = new Term(term.solver, $"({val} * {term.name})", val * term.intVar.Min(), val * term.intVar.Max());
            newTerm.basedOnVariableName = term.basedOnVariableName;
            term.solver.Add(newTerm.intVar == (val * term.intVar));
            return newTerm;
        }

        public static Expression operator >(Term left, Term right)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(left)); }
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(right, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(right)); }
            Solver solver = left.intVar.solver();
            Constraint constraint = solver.MakeGreater(left.intVar, right.intVar);
            string name = $"{left.name} > {right.name}";
            IntVar enforced = solver.MakeBoolVar(name);
            solver.Add(constraint.Var() >= enforced);
            Expression expr = new Expression(name, enforced, constraint.Var());
            return expr;
        }

        public static Expression operator <(Term left, Term right)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(left)); }
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(right, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(right)); }
            Solver solver = left.intVar.solver();
            Constraint constraint = solver.MakeLess(left.intVar, right.intVar);
            string name = $"{left.name} < {right.name}";
            IntVar enforced = solver.MakeBoolVar(name);
            solver.Add(constraint.Var() >= enforced);
            Expression expr = new Expression(name, enforced, constraint.Var());
            return expr;
        }

        public static Expression operator ==(Term left, Term right)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(left)); }
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(right, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(right)); }
            Solver solver = left.intVar.solver();
            Constraint constraint = solver.MakeEquality(left.intVar, right.intVar);
            string name = $"{left.name} == {right.name}";
            IntVar enforced = solver.MakeBoolVar(name);
            solver.Add(constraint.Var() >= enforced);
            Expression expr = new Expression(name, enforced, constraint.Var());
            return expr;
        }

        public static Expression operator !=(Term left, Term right)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(left)); }
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(right, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(right)); }
            Solver solver = left.intVar.solver();
            Constraint constraint = solver.MakeNonEquality(left.intVar, right.intVar);
            string name = $"{left.name} != {right.name}";
            IntVar enforced = solver.MakeBoolVar(name);
            solver.Add(constraint.Var() >= enforced);
            Expression expr = new Expression(name, enforced, constraint.Var());
            return expr;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (intVar.Bound())
            {
                return $"{name} = {intVar.Value()}";
            }
            else
            {
                return intVar.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Class Expression**

The class Expression keeps track of the enforced and constraint variable as well some helper methods to aid decision building and output.

The isEnforced property is true when the expression is being enforced as part of a puzzle.

The Bound() property will be true either after a decision to enforce the expression or after refutation of the decision, but also if the truth value of the expression is already determined via the propagation of the previously enforced expressions.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver;

namespace SO69225141_create_puzzles
{
    internal class Expression
    {
        public Expression(string name_, IntVar enforcedVar_, IntVar constraintVar_)
        {
            this.name = name_ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name_));
            this.enforcedVar = enforcedVar_ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enforcedVar_));
            this.constraintVar = constraintVar_ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(constraintVar_));
        }

        public string name { get; private set; }

        public IntVar enforcedVar { get; private set; }
        public IntVar constraintVar { get; private set; }

        public bool Bound()
        {
            return enforcedVar.Bound() || constraintVar.Bound();
        }

        public bool isEnforced
        {
            get
            {
                return enforcedVar.Bound() && (enforcedVar.Value() == 1);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(name);
            if (!isEnforced)
            {
                sb.Append("; not enforced");
                if (constraintVar.Bound())
                {
                    switch (constraintVar.Value())
                    {
                        case 0:
                            sb.Append("; not fulfillable");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            sb.Append("; fulfilled");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Class PuzzleCreator**

The main class that assembles the model and controls the search is called PuzzleCreator.

The method `initModel(Solver)` does the following:

- Creates the base variables a, b, c (as many as are specified in `numberOfVariables`) as `Term` objects.
- Creates combinations of the base variables and some constants as derived `Term` objects like a + 2 or 2 * a
- Creates an optional constraint for each combination of a pair of terms and a comparison operator, skipping pairs of terms based on the same variable so that expressions like  `a < a + 2` don't clutter up the model.
- Adds the `enforced` variables of the optional constraints to the decision variables list.

There is a `dump()` method to output everything to the screen for checking.

The method `solveModel(Solver)` searches for new puzzles. It creates a custom decision builder (described below) to control the search, and continues looping as long as solutions are found or until the limit on number of solutions is reached. Each solution of the model corresponds to a new puzzle.

The method `Main` of course, puts things together to allow everything to be executed.

```
using Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SO69225141_create_puzzles
{
    public class PuzzleCreator
    {
        // Parameters for model creation
        public const int numberOfVariables = 3;
        public const long minNumber = 1;
        public const long maxNumber = 3;
        public const long minConstant = 2;
        public const long maxConstant = 2;
        public const int numberOfPuzzlesToCreate = 10;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PuzzleCreator model = new PuzzleCreator();

            using (Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver.Solver solver = new Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver.Solver("Test"))
            {
                model.InitModel(solver);
                model.dump();

                model.solveModel(solver);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        // List of all the terms (a, b, ... 2 * a, a + 2, ...)
        List<Term> allTerms;
        // List of all the base variables only (a, b, c...)
        List<Term> baseVariables;
        // The decision variables for the solver, namely whether a certain expression is enforced.
        Expression[] allExpressions;

        public void InitModel(Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver.Solver solver)
        {
            allTerms = new List<Term>();
            baseVariables = new List<Term>();

            // Make the base variables
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVariables; i++)
            {
                string name = ((char)((int)'a' + i)).ToString();
                Term variable = new Term(solver, name);
                allTerms.Add(variable);
                baseVariables.Add(variable);
            }

            // Just to make it more interesting, also create some terms
            // like (a + 2) and (2 * a)
            foreach (Term term in baseVariables)
            {
                foreach (arithmeticOperators op in Enum.GetValues(typeof(arithmeticOperators)))
                {
                    switch (op)
                    {
                        case arithmeticOperators.plus:
                            for (long addend = Math.Max(1L, minConstant); addend <= maxConstant; addend++)
                            {
                                Term sum = (term + addend);
                                allTerms.Add(sum);
                            }
                            break;
                        case arithmeticOperators.times:
                            for (long factor = Math.Max(2L, minConstant); factor <= maxConstant; factor++)
                            {
                                Term product = (factor * term);
                                allTerms.Add(product);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Now create all combinations of terms and comparison operators
            var allExpressionsList = new List<Expression>();
            foreach (Term left in allTerms)
            {
                foreach (Term right in allTerms)
                {
                    if (!left.isBasedOnSameVariableAs(right))
                    {
                        foreach (comparisonOperators op in Enum.GetValues(typeof(comparisonOperators)))
                        {
                            switch (op)
                            {
                                case comparisonOperators.less:
                                    {
                                        string name = $"{left.name} < {right.name}";
                                        Expression comparison = (left < right);
                                        allExpressionsList.Add(comparison);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case comparisonOperators.equals:
                                    {
                                        string name = $"{left.name} == {right.name}";
                                        Expression comparison = (left == right);
                                        allExpressionsList.Add(comparison);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case comparisonOperators.greater:
                                    {
                                        string name = $"{left.name} > {right.name}";
                                        Expression comparison = (left > right);
                                        allExpressionsList.Add(comparison);
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            allExpressions = allExpressionsList.ToArray();
        }

        public void dump()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Complete model:");
            Console.WriteLine($"{baseVariables.Count} variables:");
            foreach (Term term in baseVariables)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(term.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{allTerms.Count} arithmetic expressions:");
            foreach (Term term in allTerms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(term.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{allExpressions.Length} comparison expressions:");
            foreach (Expression expr in allExpressions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(expr.name);
            }
        }

        public void solveModel(Solver solver)
        {
            // Could add limits if things are taking too long
            // SearchLimit limits = solver.MakeLimit(maxTime, Int64.MaxValue, Int64.MaxValue, maxSolutions, true, true);

            // Start a new solution search
            CustomDecisionBuilder decisionBuilder = new CustomDecisionBuilder(allExpressions, baseVariables);
            solver.NewSearch(decisionBuilder);

            bool solutionFound = true;
            int nsols = 0;
            string indent = "    ";
            while (solutionFound && (nsols < numberOfPuzzlesToCreate))
            {
                solutionFound = solver.NextSolution();

                if (solutionFound)
                {
                    // TODO: Verify that the given expressions really result in a unique solution for the base variables.
                    // TODO: Check if expressions can be removed and still result in a unique solution.
                    Console.WriteLine($"\r\nPuzzle {nsols}:");
                    Console.Write(indent);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Find {numberOfVariables} numbers from {minNumber} to {maxNumber} such that");
                    foreach (Expression expr in decisionBuilder.decisionsMadeFor)
                    {
                        if (expr.isEnforced)
                        {
                            Console.Write(indent);
                            Console.WriteLine(expr.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Solution:");
                    foreach (Term term in baseVariables)
                    {
                        Console.Write(indent);
                        Console.WriteLine(term.ToString());
                    }
                    nsols++;
                }
            }


            // Solver-Statistik ausgeben
            Console.WriteLine("Solver:" + solver.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("State: {0}", solver.State()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Number of solutions: {0}", solver.Solutions()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("WallTime: {0} ms", solver.WallTime()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failures: {0}", solver.Failures()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Branches: {0} ", solver.Branches()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Memory: {0} ", Solver.MemoryUsage()));
        }
    }

    enum comparisonOperators
    {
        less,
        equals,
        greater
    }

    enum arithmeticOperators
    {
        plus,
        times
    }
}
```

**Class CustomDecisionBuilder**

You may have noted that the base variables a, b, c ... are *not* part of the decision variables. The decision variables only control which expressions are active in the puzzle; the base variables are a result of those decisions.

This custom decision builder is designed to keep returning decisions on which expressions to enforce until the base variables are all bound (i.e. have specific values). After (almost) each decision, the Google solver propagates the constraints, in other words it makes inferences about the domains of all the variables in the problem to fulfill the constraints. This includes the `enforced` variables as well! (For example, if `a < b` was enforced, the solver can infer that `b < a` can no longer be enforced and sets its enforced variable to 0. When the domains of the base variables have been reduced to a single value (i.e. they are `Bound()`), the expressions being enforced are sufficient to define a puzzle having a unique solution, so the decision builder stops returning decisions to indicate that a new puzzle has been found.

The new Google.OrTools.Sat solver does not have custom decision builders, which I believe is a great lacking, so this approach could not be used with it.

Their absence completely prevents its use in the real-world application with hundreds of users for which I productively use the old solver.

The propagation is not perfect, for example after having enforced `a < b`, the propagation did not recognize that `(a + 2) < (b + 2)` must also then always be true (see puzzle 5 in the output below). Therefore, an additional decision was taken to also enforce `(a + 2) < (b + 2)`. The puzzles generated with this version are therefore overconstrained and contain redundant constraints. Some constraints could be removed and still have a unique solution for the puzzle.

The relevant method in the class is `NextWrapper(Solver)` which

- checks if all the base variables are bound and returns null to indicate "no more decisions"
- otherwise looks for the first undecided expression  and
- returns a decision to enforce the expression.

So it basically continues enforcing expressions until a new puzzle with a unique solution has been found.

When a solution has been found, the Google solver cuts that branch off of the search space by refuting the last decision. At that point, it also restores the domains of all the variables to the situation before the decision was made. Here, that means that the last expression to be enforced is freed up again, the base variables now have enlarged domains again, and the decision builder proceeds to select other expressions to enforce.

Here is the code of the custom decision builder.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver;

namespace SO69225141_create_puzzles
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom decision builder for puzzle creation expression enforcing variables.
    /// Decides to enforce expressions until the base variables are all bound, then no more decisions
    /// </summary>
    internal class CustomDecisionBuilder : DecisionBuilder
    {
        Expression[] expressions;
        List<Term> baseVariables;
        private HashSet<Expression> decisionsMadeFor_ = new HashSet<Expression>();

        public CustomDecisionBuilder(Expression[] expressions_, List<Term> baseVariables_)
        {
            this.expressions = expressions_ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expressions_));
            this.baseVariables = baseVariables_ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(baseVariables_));
        }

        public IEnumerable<Expression> decisionsMadeFor
        {
            get
            {
                return decisionsMadeFor_;
            }
        }

        public override Decision NextWrapper(Solver solver)
        {
            // Are the base variables all bound?
            bool allBaseVariablesBound = true;
            foreach (Term baseVariable in baseVariables)
            {
                if (!baseVariable.intVar.Bound())
                {
                    allBaseVariablesBound = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (allBaseVariablesBound)
            {
                // Done with decisions, all variables are bound.
                return null;
            }

            // Find first expression that is neither enforced nor already fixed via propagation
            for (int i = 0; i < expressions.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!expressions[i].Bound())
                {
                    decisionsMadeFor_.Add(expressions[i]);
                    return solver.MakeAssignVariableValue(expressions[i].enforcedVar, 1L);
                }
            }

            // All variables bound !!!!????, no more decisions to make.
            // This means all expressions are definitely enforced (or definitely not) 
            // but the solution is still not unique. Consider this as failure
            return solver.MakeFailDecision();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample output of the problem:

```
Puzzle 0:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b < c
Solution:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3

Puzzle 1:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    b < (2 * a)
Solution:
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 3

Puzzle 2:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    b == (2 * a)
Solution:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 2

Puzzle 3:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    c < (a + 2)
    c < (2 * a)
Solution:
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 3

Puzzle 4:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    c < (a + 2)
    c == (2 * a)
Solution:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 2

Puzzle 5:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    c < (a + 2)
    (a + 2) < (b + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * b)
    (a + 2) < (c + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * c)
    (2 * a) == b
Solution:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 2

Puzzle 6:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    c < (a + 2)
    (a + 2) < (b + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * b)
    (a + 2) < (c + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * c)
    (2 * a) > b
Solution:
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 3

Puzzle 7:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    c < (a + 2)
    (a + 2) < (b + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * b)
    (a + 2) < (c + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * c)
    (2 * a) == c
Solution:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 2

Puzzle 8:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    c < (a + 2)
    (a + 2) < (b + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * b)
    (a + 2) < (c + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * c)
    (2 * a) > c
Solution:
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 3

Puzzle 9:
    Find 3 numbers from 1 to 3 such that
    a < b
    a < c
    b == c
    b < (a + 2)
    c < (a + 2)
    (a + 2) < (b + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * b)
    (a + 2) < (c + 2)
    (a + 2) < (2 * c)
    (2 * a) < (b + 2)
    (2 * a) < (2 * b)
    (2 * a) < (c + 2)
    (2 * a) < (2 * c)
    (b + 2) == (c + 2)
    (b + 2) < (2 * c)
Solution:
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 3
```

The method isn't 100% accurate, because the propagation done by the solver afer a decision is not perfect. Some dependencies can only be discovered by backtracking, and it might also not be recognized that a particular expression has become redundant. For this reason, the puzzles generated may have more expressions in them than would be strictly necessary to find a unique solution.

Although I did a cursory check of the output, the program is not 100% tested by any means. It has a couple of TODO's in it to verify the solutions in place and remove expressions that are redundant...

Comment: I edited the answer to resolve a bug I noticed shortly after posting it.

Comment: Thx a lot. I'll look into it, but might take a couple of days :-) Transferring from C# to Python should not be a problem as the language-independent modeling is what challenges us here :-)